# Tastypie resource model

Tags: tastypie, mongoengine

I'm working on tastypie with mongoengine. I have core file but when i use them in resource file it gives me the error:

```
'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'model'
```

Resource file

```
class GameResource(ModelResource):
class Meta:
    queryset = Sports.objects.all()
    resource_name = 'sports'
```

core file

```
from mongoengine import *
class Sports(Document):
    game = StringField(max_length=50,required=True)
    name = StringField(max_length=50,required=True)
```

Here is the error messages I am getting:

```
{"error_message": "", "traceback": "Traceback (most recent call last):\n\n  File \"c:\\virtualenvs\\env\\lib\\site-packages\\django_tastypie-0.9.11-
py2.6.egg\\tastypie\\resources.py\", line 192, in wrapper\n    
response = callback(request, *args, **kwargs)\n\n  File \"c:\\virtualenvs\\env\\lib\\site-packages\\django_tastypie-0.9.11-py2.6.egg\\tastypie\\resources.py\", 
line 397, in dispatch_list\n    return self.dispatch('list', request, **kwargs)\n\n  File \"c:\\virtualenvs\\env\\lib\\site-packages\\django_tastypie-0.9.11-py2.6.egg\\tastypie\\resources.py\", line 427, in dispatch\n    
response = method(request, **kwargs)\n\n  File \"c:\\virtualenvs\\env\\lib\\site-packages\\django_tastypie-0.9.11-py2.6.egg\\tastypie\\resources.py\",
line 1029, in get_list\n    objects = self.obj_get_list(request=request, **self.remove_api_resource_names(kwargs))\n\n  File \"c:\\virtualenvs\\env\\lib\\site-packages\\django_tastypie-0.9.11-py2.6.egg\\tastypie\\resources.py\", line 884, in obj_get_list\n    raise NotImplementedError()\n\nNotImplementedError\n"}
```

Answer (score 2):

For sure your indentation is wrong, the Meta class should be part of the GameResource class, like so:

```
class GameResource(ModelResource):
    class Meta:
        queryset = Sports.objects.all()
        resource_name = 'sports'
```

If that doesn't fix the problem, could you please paste the full traceback? The error you're mentioning doesn't seem to be triggered in this code (there is no 'model' attribute anywhere). Therefore it's hard to understand what the error is exactly and where exactly does it occur.

Comment: indentation is due to copy paste and im  working on mongo engine so i m not using any model i m using document.

Comment: Come now, you've pasted the traceback for NotImplementedError, this is not what you mention in your question. Please straighten your question out, and consider using code formatting for the traceback to make it easier to read.

Comment: Also if you're not using the Django model then why inherit from ModelResource ? You should inherit from Resource and write your custom data manipulation code. See http://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/latest/non_orm_data_sources.html

Comment: do you have any example with mongo engine. in this example they used riak  but i m not getting any help for mongo engine

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't. All you need to do is write some custom methods though. Depending on your needs you need to define some of the methods listed here: http://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/latest/non_orm_data_sources.html#approach You could also look at the source of the ModelResource class to see how they handle Django models, this should give you some ideas. Fortunately, they're not so hard to grasp :)

Answer (score -1):

If anyone needs an example about how to create a Tastypie resource model for MongoDB, inheriting from Resource, here is a very useful link:

http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/2830/